# How to capture screen from multiple monitor in ActionScript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, screenshot

I want to capture screen in my second monitor, Currently i am using CmdCapture.exe application to take screenshot in certain time interval but it is only capturing the screen from primary monitor so i have no knowledge how to capture screen from secondary monitor using CmdCapture.exe.

I am using the following codes to take screenshot:

```
var cmdScreenCaputeLocation:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("assets\\CmdCapture.exe");
var nativeProcessStartInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
nativeProcessStartInfo.executable = cmdScreenCaputeLocation;

var args: Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
var uid:String = "tempImg"+imgCounter+"";
args.push("/f", (uid+".jpg"),"/d",""+screencaptureDir+"", "/q 70");
nativeProcessStartInfo.arguments = args;
var nativeProcess:NativeProcess = new NativeProcess();
nativeProcess.addEventListener(NativeProcessExitEvent.EXIT,screenCaptureNativeProcessComplated);
nativeProcess.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_DATA,screenCapturOonErrorS);
nativeProcess.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.STANDARD_INPUT_IO_ERROR,screenCaptureOnError);
nativeProcess.start(nativeProcessStartInfo);
imgCounter++;
```

So anybody have an idea how to take screenshot from secondary monitor using CmdCapture.exe or using any other applications which can be run in actionscript nativeprocess command, please help me.

Comment: please post your current code, and then it will be easier to help you

Comment: looking at the docs from CmdCapture you have no control over what is being recorded.

Comment: Hi @RobinvandenBogaard ,any suggestion or any other way to resolve this problem.

Comment: @Ashish, obvious suggestion is try a different screen capture tool that actually says it supports multiple screens. You could try BoxCutter or even MultiMonitorTool. For worst case, just find a tool that flips the displays so that secondary becomes primary, now you screen grab the "new" primary, then switch back screens to usual setup.

Comment: Thanks @VC.One for your valuable comments and i found that BoxCutter is supporting the multi screen but i have no knowledge what are the command line arguments BoxCutter is taking for screenshot (i.e for CmdCapture i am passing the command line arguments like ("/f", "image1.jpg","/d","screenCaptureDirectory", "/q 70")), so if you know please help me to find that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding **[BoxCutter](https://github.com/mdrasmus/boxcutter)** docs...

> Usage : `boxcutter [OPTIONS] [OUTPUT_FILENAME]`
>
> OPTIONS
>   `-c`, = coords X1,Y1,X2,Y2    capture the rectangle (X1,Y1)-(X2,Y2).
>   `-f`, = fullscreen            capture the full screen.
>   `-h`, = help                  display help message.

**usage** : `boxcutter -c -AA,BB,CC,DD testgrab.png`

Where numbers for : 
`AA` is starting origin along X-axis (left/right) 
`BB` is starting origin along Y-axis (up/down) 
 
`CC` is grab width along X-axis (left/right) 
 
`DD` is grab height along Y-axis (up/down)

As an example let's test : **Screen 1** is w=1280 & h=800, **Screen 2** is w=1024 & h=768.

**grabbing examples** :

- for **monitor `1`** only use: `boxcutter -c 0,0,1280,800 testgrab.png`
- for **monitor `2`** only use: `boxcutter -c 1280,0,2304,768 testgrab.png`
- for **both monitors `1` & `2`** together use: `boxcutter -c 0,0,2304,800 testgrab.png`

Note that **Screen 2** begins after the width of **Screen 1** ends. So to grab both screens at same time `CC` must be total of added widths of **Screen 1** + **Screen 2**. For height `DD` must use biggest height (from one of those two screens) to avoid any unwanted cropping.

Try this in your code

```
args.push("-c");
args.push("0", "0", "myWidth", "myHeight");
args.push("testgrab.png");
```

where : **myWidth** & **myHeight** = required width & height of grab area. .

PS : Check this **[Article](http://bird1110.blogspot.com/2010/11/screenshot-of-full-screen-of-multiple.html)** since it might help you with settings for multiple monitors...

Comment: Hi @VC.One, thanks for quick replay i have tried the above codes and that are working fine if i am passing the following codes 
     `args.push("-f");
     args.push("E:\\screenshot.png");` But if i am trying to pass coordinate like `args.push("-c");
     args.push("0","0","1440","900");
     args.push("E:\\screenshot.png");
     nativeProcessStartInfo.arguments = args;` then the above code not working, can you please figure out where i am doing wrong.

Comment: I will check later when back on Flash, You could try `args.push("0","900","1440","900");`. The thing is you want to draw a rectangle but setting zero (top left) for both starting x1 (across) and y1 (down) means you'll end up with a triangle.

Comment: Hi @VC.One, do you know any command line tool for **mac os** who can take screenshot like CmdCapture.exe and boxcutter.exe, because i also want to do same for **mac**.

Comment: I added an update if you still need the extra info about BoxCutter. I don't use Mac so can't recommend software. Good luck.